# How can a Windows PowerShell script pass its parameters through to another script invocation?

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0, 32bit-64bit

In short, I'm just looking for the PowerShell equivalent of how a batch file can call a script with the same parameters...

```
"%~dpnx0" %*
```

...where `"%~dpnx0"` expands to the absolute path of the script and `%*` is expanded to the list of parameters.  Is there an easy way to replicate `%*`?  Or, at least, a way that works?

I have a PowerShell script that uses the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace to read data from an `Excel` workbook.  Because there is no 64-bit implementation of the Microsoft Jet provider, the script needs to be run from a 32-bit PowerShell session.  Rather than simply having the script fail with an error message if it's run from a 64-bit session, I'd like to have the 64-bit session invoke the script in and retrieve the results from a 32-bit session.  I found that this can be done using the [`Start-Job` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347692.aspx) with the `-RunAs32` switch, however I'm having trouble providing a value for the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

I came up with the following to search for whichever script parameters have values and build a command line out of them:

```
function GetValueText([Object] $value)
{
    [String] $text = if ($value -eq $null) {
        '$null';
    } elseif ($value -is [String]) {
        "'$value'";
    } elseif ($value -is [Array]) {
        '@({0})' -f (($value | ForEach-Object { GetValueText $_ }) -join ', ');
    } else {
        "$value";
    }

    return $text;
}

if ([IntPtr]::Size -gt 4)
{
    [String] $scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
    [String[]] $parameters = @(
        $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys `
        | ForEach-Object {
            [Object] $parameterValue = Get-Variable -Name $_ -ValueOnly;

            if ($parameterValue -ne $null)
            {
                [String] $parameterValueText = GetValueText $parameterValue;

                '-{0}' -f $_;
                $parameterValueText;
            }
        }
    );
    [Object] $job = Start-Job -FilePath $scriptPath -RunAs32 -ArgumentList $parameters;
    [Object[]] $data = $job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job;

    $data;
}
else
{
    # Retrieve data...
}
```

When it gets to the `Start-Job` line it generates an error with message `"Cannot convert value "-Argument1" to type "System.Int32[]""`.  `-Argument1` is the script's first parameter and is of type `[Int32[]]`, so does this mean that `-ArgumentList` only works with positional and not named parameters?

I've also tried simplifying it to...

```
param(
    [String] $stringArg,
    [Int32] $int32Arg
)

$PSBoundParameters;

if ([IntPtr]::Size -gt 4)
{
    [String] $scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
    [Object] $job = Start-Job -FilePath $scriptPath -RunAs32 -ArgumentList @PSBoundParameters;

    $job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job;
}
else
{
    Get-Date;
}
```

...but when I run `.\Test.ps1 'string' 12345` from a 64-bit session, it displays...

```
Key                                                         Value
---                                                         -----
stringArg                                                   string
int32Arg                                                    12345
Start-Job : Missing an argument for parameter 'ArgumentList'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object[]' and try again.
At X:\Test.ps1:11 char:72
+     [Object] $job = Start-Job -FilePath $scriptPath -RunAs32 -ArgumentList <<<<  @PSBoundParameters;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand
```

...so `@PSBoundParameters` seems to evaluate to `$null`.  I'm not sure why this isn't working or what else to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably going to look a little odd, but:

```
param(
[String] $stringArg,
[Int32] $int32Arg
)

if ([IntPtr]::Size -gt 4)
{
[String] $scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;

$params = @()
$psboundparameters.keys |
  foreach {
      $params += "-$($_)"
      $params +=  $psboundparameters.$_
      }


$sb = [scriptblock]::Create(@"
&'$scriptpath' $params
"@)

[Object] $job = Start-Job -scriptblock $sb -RunAs32 
$job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job;
}
else
{
Get-Date
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That fails if the script path has spaces in it, but I was able to fix it by passing `"& '$scriptpath' $(&{$args} @psboundparameters)"` to `[scriptblock]::Create()`.  After making that change, the script works when called with no parameters, but if I run `.\Test.ps1 'string' 12345`, it fails at `Receive-Job` with `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'int32Arg'. Cannot convert value "string" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."`  Can you explain what this is doing?  `&{$args}`, in particular, is confusing me.

Comment: That will allow you to pass named parameters. Splatting a hash table produces a set of "-parameter value" strings from the key/value pairs of the hash table. But you can't evaluate a splat by itself. &{$args} provides a script block to accept the splat that will echo back the "-parameter value" strings and then they will be included in the script block that is passed to the job.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  On my system (W7 x64) it returns the date, and running get-job shows that the created job is still there, with a status of "Completed'.

Comment: I am also on 64-bit Windows 7.  I tried your updated script and `.\Test.ps1`, `.\Test.ps1 123`, `.\Test.ps1 123 456`, `.\Test.ps1 123 456 foo`, and `.\Test.ps1 -int32Arg 123` all work.  `.\Test.ps1 foo`, `.\Test.ps1 foo 123`, `.\Test.ps1 -stringArg foo` and anything else where the first two parameters cannot be converted to an integer fail with the error `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'int32Arg'. Cannot convert value "foo" to type "System.Int32".`  I don't understand why it's trying to match those tokens up with the second positional parameter.

Comment: I do not understand that either.  Running that script as: PS C:\scripts\test\test scripts> ./test.ps1 'string' 12345 or PS C:\scripts\test\test scripts> ./test.ps1 -stringarg 'string' -int32arg 12345  both return the date, as expected on my system. Note - that's from a ps console, not ISE.

Comment: I did have to edit your script because `@"` and `"@` need to appear at the very beginning of the lines, but I can't imagine that'd introduce any problems.  I write my scripts with PowerGUI, but have been testing this from a console session just because PowerGUI sometimes introduces some little differences.  Starting the session with `powershell.exe -NoProfile` doesn't make any difference.  I'm using PowerShell 2.0, not the 3.0 preview or anything.  Hmmm.

Comment: I am runnin the 3.0 preview.  Let me do some more testing.

Comment: OK. There is a difference between the way &{$args} @hash evaluates between V2 and V3.  In V3 the keys will be prepended with a '-' (which I would expect).  I made a change to the code that does work, but I don't really like it because it's now broken in V3.  I may need to go back and look at using an array instead.

Comment: OK, changed it to an array splat, and that seems to work in V2 and in V3.  Sorry for leading you down that rabbit hole.  Maybe somebody else will have a better solution.

Comment: No problem.  I did notice one time that the command line that was being built didn't have any hyphens before the parameter names, so I guess that explains why it wasn't matching up the parameters to the correct positions.  Your updated code works perfectly, though.  I just needed to change the second line of the `foreach` to `$params += GetValueText $psboundparameters.$_` (using the function defined in my question) so it works properly with my array parameters.  Thanks for your help and for sticking with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-launch your script programmatically as a 32 bit process like this:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $stringArg,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32] $int32Arg
)

if ([IntPtr]::Size -ne 4) {
    $p = $PSBoundParameters
    $32bitPs = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    $myArgs = @($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    $myArgs += ( $p.Keys | % { ('-' + $_), $p.Item($_) } )
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $32bitPs -ArgumentList $myArgs
    exit
}

Write-Host "Hi I'm a 32 bit process, my args are:"
$PSBoundParameters
# Do 32 bit stuff here...
Read-Host "Press enter to quit"
```

Comment: This is the way I originally thought of doing it and would work fine for a script that is purely writing to the console, files, etc. without yielding any data to the pipeline, but I realized that any data that is retrieved will be stuck in the 32-bit instance of the script with no (easy?) way to return it to the parent 64-bit instance.  If you add `Get-Date` to the end of the script you'll see it in the pipeline when run directly from a 32-bit session, but from a 64-bit session it gets lost.  I'd like the 64-bit handling to be transparent such that I can still pipe this script to cmdlets.

Comment: If you have to mix the two then relaunching the whole process won't work so we'll and creating a background job would be better. If everything works as a 32 bit script you could just run all the code that way.